# format number to currency haml

Tags: haml

I am working on a code written in haml, for converting number to currency developer has coded like following.

to_currency payment.amount

It is converting number 5 as $5.00, but this is a credit amount so I need to display it as ($5.00) instead of $5.00.

Any recommendations what should I change in to_currency?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that this is really a HAML question, since you're asking what to change in your **to_currency** function, which is surely held in a controller or helper file, not a HAML file. However, you can interpolate the function into any HAML file like this:

```
You save (#{to_currency(payment.amount)})
```

If **to_currency** were to return $5.00, the above HAML line would produce:

```
You save ($5.00)
```

Depending on your code, this might be the better method, anyway. That way, you can leave your original **to_currency** function alone, which may be providing results to other portions of the app which expect the results with no parentheses.